# I can't access members of a child class through functions, how do I?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

Okay, so my situation is really complex to a relativity new person to C++ like me. I'm making a game (AGK library) and I have a framework class that is the base class for all of the game's objects to have standard functions like `frameEvent` and such that are to be overwritten by the child object.

That's all fine and dandy, and I've gotten about 70% through development, but I ran across one vital problem.

To make life easier while processing the game, each object that is a part of the game is just a pointer in a vector of type Framework*. Framework being the base class. I was told that making it a pointer allows me to have child objects of different types as long as they're a pointer as well. So far it's worked out.

Every frame, the global object runs through the vector of all the objects and runs their

1. `frameEvent`
2. `frameEndEvent` -- Can't be overriden
3. `drawEvent`

They're really just functions. So in the enemy's bullet class, I need to check if it collides with `oPlayer`, so I have a functions in the global class (The global class is passed to the objects in their frame event so they can communicate with other objects.) that grabs a given object.

It searches through all of the objects to find the parameter object -- so if I pass `new oPlayer`, it will return the real `oPlayer` pointer in the game.

When the bullet collides with the player, it needs to lower the player's health and then destroy itself. So at the create function for the bullet, it creates a dummy player then locates the real one using the global class function. The code is

```
//Find the player
oPlayer* tempPlayer = new oPlayer;
playerChecker = ObjGlobal->classToObject(tempPlayer);
tempPlayer->objectDestroy();
```

That code works, but it needs `playerChecker` to be type Framework* because that's what `classToObject` returns. But when I later use that pointer, I can't access the player's members even though that's the player's pointer.
    playerChecker->hitPoints--;
`hitPoints` is exclusive to `oPlayer`. I think it's called object splicing or slicing, but I thought that's what using pointers fixed.

So I tried to make `playerChecker` type oPlayer*, but it says that Framework* can't be converted to it. So I have no idea what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try to make a small example program to show in this question.  There are too many details that we have to guess about regarding your code.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding fully what's going on, but would you be able to call a function if the player collides with the bullet rather than if the bullet collides with the player, in which case it seems that you could just make the adjustments to the player's hitpoints there.

Comment: This sounds a lot like virtual member functions would be quite useful. May not entirely solve your issue, but since you don't mention that any of your member functions are virtual, perhaps you aren't using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Framework*` from `classToObject` can be downcast to a `oPlayer*` using a `dynamic_cast`, like so:

```
oPlayer* playerChecker = dynamic_cast<oPlayer*>(ObjGlobal->classToObject(tempPlayer));
if (oPlayer) {
    // cast succeeded, do stuff with the pointer
}
```

`dynamic_cast` is a C++ type cast operator just like the C-style cast, with some special properties. It is specifically designed to convert between pointers or references to polymorphic objects (like your `oPlayer`, which can be treated as both a `Framework` and an `oPlayer`). It also adds a run-time check which verifies that the object you're trying to downcast is indeed an instance of the class you're trying to cast to. If it isn't, it will return a null pointer, or in the case of references, throw an exception.

Your code will also work with a C-style cast or a `static_cast` (which is much like a C-style cast with compile-type type checking).

```
static_cast<oPlayer*>(ObjGlobal->classToObject(tempPlayer)) // static_cast
(oPlayer*)ObjGlobal->classToObject(tempPlayer) // C-style cast
```

These have less overhead because of the lack of a run-time check, but that also means that they are unsafe unless you can guarantee that the pointer you're casting points to an object of the correct type. Also, since `dynamic_cast` has a very specific use, it makes it clear what your intent is.

Comment: It fixed the problem, thanks! But I have no clue whats going on... Would you mind explaining what dynamic_cast is? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you're getting? Please post this, as we can't offer much help otherwise.

If I had to guess, you forgot to add `public:` to your `class FrameWork`. This, or you don't have setters/getters in your class.